# Getting Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject error

Tags: asp.net, json

I am getting this error below when trying to de-serialize JSON into a dataset. What could be the problem? Any help is appreciated.

**Error**: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject. Path 'status', line 1, position 11.

`Dim ds As DataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataSet)(strJSON)`

Here is example of JSON:

`{
    "status": {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "code": 0,
        "msg": "SuccessWithResult",
        "total": 10000,
        "page": 1,
        "pagesize": 10
    },
    "property": [
         {
            "identifier": {
                "obPropId": 15096656312086,
                "fips": "12086",
                "apn": "0232340220100",
                "apnOrig": "232340220100",
                "attomId": 150966563
            },
            "lot": {
                "lotSize1": 0.249
            },
            "address": {
                "country": "US",
                "countrySubd": "FL",
                "line1": "2014 ALTON RD",
                "line2": "MIAMI BEACH, FL 33140",
                "locality": "Miami Beach",
                "matchCode": "ExaStr",
                "oneLine": "2014 ALTON RD, MIAMI BEACH, FL 33140",
                "postal1": "33140",
                "postal2": "4532",
                "postal3": "C007"
            },
            "location": {
                "accuracy": "Street",
                "elevation": 0.0,
                "latitude": "25.796309",
                "longitude": "-80.140216",
                "distance": 0.0,
                "geoid": "CO12086, CS1292171, DB1200390, MT30002544, ND0000461513, ND0004455664, PL1245025, RS0000471909, ZI33140"
            },
            "summary": {
                "propclass": "Single Family Residence / Townhouse",
                "propsubtype": "MISCELLANEOUS INDUSTRIAL",
                "proptype": "SFR",
                "yearbuilt": 1927,
                "propLandUse": "SFR",
                "propIndicator": "10"
            },
            "building": {
                "size": {
                    "universalsize": 4358
                },
                "rooms": {
                    "bathstotal": 5.0,
                    "beds": 6
                }
            },
            "vintage": {
                "lastModified": "2020-3-13",
                "pubDate": "2020-3-14"
            }
        },
        {
            "identifier": {
                "obPropId": 862064312086,
                "fips": "12086",
                "apn": "0232340220080",
                "apnOrig": "232340220080",
                "attomId": 8620643
            },
            "lot": {
                "lotSize1": 0.2063
            },
            "address": {
                "country": "US",
                "countrySubd": "FL",
                "line1": "2008 ALTON RD",
                "line2": "MIAMI BEACH, FL 33140",
                "locality": "Miami Beach",
                "matchCode": "ExaStr",
                "oneLine": "2008 ALTON RD, MIAMI BEACH, FL 33140",
                "postal1": "33140",
                "postal2": "4532",
                "postal3": "C007"
            },
            "location": {
                "accuracy": "Street",
                "elevation": 0.0,
                "latitude": "25.796222",
                "longitude": "-80.140290",
                "distance": 0.0,
                "geoid": "CO12086, CS1292171, DB1200390, MT30002544, ND0000461513, ND0004455664, PL1245025, RS0000471909, ZI33140"
            },
            "summary": {
                "propclass": "Single Family Residence / Townhouse",
                "propsubtype": "MISCELLANEOUS INDUSTRIAL",
                "proptype": "SFR",
                "yearbuilt": 1920,
                "propLandUse": "SFR",
                "propIndicator": "10"
            },
            "building": {
                "size": {
                    "universalsize": 3037
                },
                "rooms": {
                    "bathstotal": 3.0,
                    "beds": 4
                }
            },
            "vintage": {
                "lastModified": "2020-3-13",
                "pubDate": "2020-3-14"
            }
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: Could you please add what language / environment you are using? (I suppose that it's VisualBasic, not?) Tag the question correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, sorry its vb.net. Thanks

Comment: The error means you are trying to de-serialize into an array (`Expected StartArray`) but the JSON string of the input represent an object (it starts with `{`). You would need to first deserialize into an object then use the field `property`, which is an array, to build the dataset.

Comment: I'm not familiar with vb .net so I don't know how you do that, but there should be some resource online.

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple thing need to do when you are getting response concatenate array symbol around in start and end of result

```
dynamic result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("["+result+"]", typeof(DataTable));
```